Relative path issue when executing ES module file with node
I need little help with building custome npm command to run ES module file, I am using this file to seed my database.
i am using sequelize in a Node api (not using sequelize CLI or migrations) i want to make an npm command to run the seeding file (it is just a custom  writen .js file with import statements to seed the modals) i have type=module in my package.json. means i am using ES module in all my project, I tried adding the command 'db-seed:'node /commands/db-seed.js', but now whenever I run this command it gives me an error showing that the node instead of using the current project directory which is "f:/laragon/www/kanban-board-app/", uses base directory F:/, although I am running this command from my project's directory due to this it is not able to find my import statement modules that are available in project's root directory.
what I tried to solve this problem:
if I use process.cwd()  it gives an error unexpected identifier process, even I have imported process from node:process
PS F:\laragon\www\kanban-board-node-app> node commands/db-seed.js
file:///F:/laragon/www/kanban-board-node-app/commands/db-seed.js:18
import  { hashMake } from process.cwd("../utils/helpers.js");
                      ^^^^^^^

  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'process'
    at compileSourceTextModule (node:internal/modules/esm/utils:337:16)
   at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:166:18)        
   at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:416:14)
   at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
   at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:88:21)

Node.js v22.0.0
PS F:\laragon\www\kanban-board-node-app>

if I do relative path solution which is
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

// Resolve the current directory
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

import {hashMake} from path.resolve(__dirname, '../utils/helpers.js');

it gives me an error unexpected identifier path(pointing to line path.resolve);
it doesn't leave any other options for me to try. And I still unable to run that js file using npm commands
here is my package.json
 {
"name": "kanban-board-app",
"description": "This is a kanban board app based on node js express and mongodb",
"private": true,
"version": "0.0.0",
"type": "module",
"main":"server.js",
  "scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon –experimental-modules server.js",
  "db-refresh":"node  commands/db-refresh.js",
  "db-seed":"node commands/db-seed.js",
  "watch": "node --watch server.js",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
"author": "Zeeshan",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
   "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
   "cloudinary": "^2.0.1",
  "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
  "config": "^3.3.11",
  "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "datauri": "^4.1.0",
  "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
  "dotenv": "^16.4.2",
  "express": "^4.18.2",
  "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
  "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.2.0",
  "express-rate-limit": "^7.1.5",
  "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
  "helmet": "^7.1.0",
  "http-status-codes": "^2.3.0",
  "immer": "^10.1.1",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
  "morgan": "^1.10.0",
  "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
  "mysql2": "^3.9.3",
  "nanoid": "^5.0.5",
  "nodemailer": "^6.9.14",
  "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
  "react-select": "^5.8.0",
  "sequelize": "^6.37.2",
  "winston": "^3.11.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@eslint/js": "^9.1.1",
  "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
  "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.15",
  "eslint": "^8.57.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
  "globals": "^15.1.0",
  "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  }
}

and here are my import statements from "./commands/db-seed.js" file code
 import path from 'path';
 import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);


import process,{cwd} from "node:process";
import sequelize from "../db.js";
import { v1 as uuidv1, v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

  // Resolve the path to helpers.js
  // const helpersPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../utils/helpers.js');

  // 
 // import { hashMake } from helpersPath;
 import  { hashMake } from process.cwd("../utils/helpers.js");
 import User from "../models/UserModel.js";
 import Workspace from "../models/Workspace.js";
 import Board from "../models/BoardModel.js";
 import UserWorkspace from "../models/UserWorkspace.js";
 import BoardColumn from "../models/BoardColumnModel.js";
 import Task from "../models/TaskModel.js";
 import SubTask from "../models/SubTask.js";
 import TaskDiscussion from "../models/TaskDiscussion.js";
 import {
    trunOffForeignKeyCheckAndTruncateTable,
    checkIfTableExists,
    } from "../../utils/helpers.js";


You will not be able to use the import x from './y' syntax to accomplish this, as it's not possible to make the ./y part dynamic.
However, you can use the import() function.
Example:
const myModule = await import(`some/path/that/can/even/include/a${variable}`);


i tried doing it like this "
const myModule = await import("../utils/helpers.js");
// import { hashMake } from myModule;
console.log(myModule);"
but got the same error
internal/modules/esm/resolve:264
throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'F:\laragon\www\utils\helpers.js' imported from F:\laragon\www\kanban-board-node-app\commands\db-seed.js

node is not looking for module in project's directory, it looks out of project's directory. and i tried different ways to make it look in project's folder directory, none worked.
with your suggestion, i even got an error saying unexpected identifier myModule,

@MuhammadZeeshan the main point here is that with this syntax cwd() can be used. Unexpected identifier makes no sense here unless there was an error on a previous line.

Actually given the snippet you shared the second line makes no sense.

yeah man that is the problem and that is why I posted it here, is gives same error with both process and Path although they are already imported above, i tried looking for solutions of different sites and everywhere only these two solution are available for ES module file, either they are saying import should work or use process.cwd(), the third solution from chatGPT to create __filename and __dirname variables also gives the same error  'unexpected variable path'. I don't know what to do yet

@MuhammadZeeshan you don't have to import the same thing twice. After importing with my syntax, you should be able to use myModule.hashMake for example.

Hi @Evert  Thanks again for your response. I just tried your given syntax again and as you said i should be able to use myModule.hashMake, i tried it and still got this error
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'F:\laragon\www\utils\helpers.js' imported from F:\laragon\www\kanban-board-node-app\commands\db-seed.js
you can see that node is looking for untils/helpers.js  out side of my projects directory . and this is the main problem, here is how i imported the helper.js
const helpers = await import("../utils/helpers.js");
used ../ to make it look out of commands folder

if you have time and are interested to solve it with me you can contact me on Skype "live:zeeshanawan1998" Also you can see the code on https://github.com/Zeeshan607/agile-board-app

@MuhammadZeeshan the point of my answer is that using the const foo = await import(...) syntax you will be able to use variables in the argument. This means you can use functions such as process.cwd() in the argument, which is not possible in the import foo from '...' syntax. So try to put a full path to together when you call await import()

bro i tried both process. cwd() and const helpers = await import(path.resolve(__dirname,"/utils/helpers.js")); inside await import() syntax and still got error
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'F:\laragon\www\utils\helpers.js' imported from F:\laragon\www\kanban-board-node-app\commands\db-seed.js
i don't know why this is not working, it should work because ChatGTP also suggest the same things that i already tried

Share what you tried with process.cwd. Please don't call me bro.

tried const helpers = await import(process.cwd("../utils/helpers.js"));
got error "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'F:\laragon\www\utils\helpers.js' imported from F:\laragon\www\kanban-board-node-app\commands\db-seed.js"

@MuhammadZeeshan process.cwd() returns the current directory. It does not accept any arguments. Try console.logging process.cwd() to see what it returns.

I found the solution with the help of ChatGPT and @Evert.
so this is how it seems to be working
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath, pathToFileURL } from 'url';

// Get the current directory
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
// Convert paths to URLs for dynamic import
const helpersPath = pathToFileURL(path.resolve(__dirname, 
'../utils/helpers.js')).href;

// const sequelize = await import(sequelizePath);
const helpers = await import(helpersPath);

I don't know why but only this helper.js file was getting the error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]. All other imports are working as they were which you can see below
import sequelize from "../db.js";
import User from "../models/UserModel.js";
import Workspace from "../models/Workspace.js";
import Board from "../models/BoardModel.js";
import UserWorkspace from "../models/UserWorkspace.js";
import BoardColumn from "../models/BoardColumnModel.js";
import Task from "../models/TaskModel.js";
import SubTask from "../models/SubTask.js";
import TaskDiscussion from "../models/TaskDiscussion.js";

